# wrongly tagging

Tags: support, tags

Does the community pay lot of attention to tags? And what happens if a question is wrongly? What does it cost me? If it costs me nothing shouldn't the community take a look at it, because I for instance, am often lazy looking for already created tags that relevant to my question. This is often due to the recurrence of the characters typed in the tag field. Example, 'sin' will appear as 'sinsinsinsinsinsinsin' and in the end, there is an alert of characters more than 25. I struggle with this everytime with my phone opera mini before some magic happens. Who else uses the phone version, he will see what am talking about. I know nothing concerning programming, etc. So please reply in raw language.
PS: had the same problem with this very question. Difficult to add the tag 'bug'.

Answer (score 2):

You as a community member are responsible for tagging your questions appropriately. Tags are the lifeblood of any stack exchange and give important context to your question. You should *always* try to find at least one (if not more) appropriate tags for your question. If the tags you need are not available then please flag your question or leave a comment asking for the appropriate tag to be added to your question.

One of the ways that community members with sufficient reputation can help the site is by doing any one of the following related to tags:

- Retagging questions that are poorly tagged
- Adding tags where extra context would help the question
- Editing tag wikis and wiki summaries to help give tags more meaning
- Spotting duplicate tags and raising them on meta or proposing them in the tag synonym tool.

Usually if you tag a question poorly someone will come along and edit it into shape. If poor tagging becomes a continuous issue moderator actions may be necessary. Bad tags hurt the community, poorly tagging on purpose is not helpful and may result in discipline.

Didn't notice the mobile issues the first time through. what exactly is wrong there? Honestly I've found that SE's mobile site is OK for consuming and maybe writing answers, but it may be far to cumbersome for asking questions.

Just tried out creating a question on my phone, as far as tags, keep an eye on the row immediately above the text box, when you start typing a tag some javascript runs there that will give you options to choose from, tap the correct tag and you're home free.

Comment: Thanks much wax. So is there anything they can do to make it less cumbersome? I also have this question about duplicates. Its also very difficult to check that for questions. Example again is the SIN tag which seems to have

Comment: @Nok, in the non-mobile format there is a list of potential duplicates that show when you type your question title. I haven't tried composing on mobile. The problem with mobile browsing is that there is tons of ajax on these pages, some of which is included in the mobile version. Just tried a new question, the dupe detector is not active on mobile, however, I will add something about tags.

Comment: I also noticed that chat is just impossible as it requires flash player. Skype chat mobile enables messages to pop the moment it is sent. Yahoo messenger also allows you to refresh the page in order to see the newest message. Now i cannot use this privilege untill I get a PC. That notwithstanding, I love the site and am glad to be addicted to this and not facebook.

Comment: @Nok no, SE chat requires HTML 5, I chat just fine on my phone with the default android browser. Its not good, but I can do it.

Comment: What do I do then? Am using sony ericsson k800i with opera mini. I click on chat and I see 'Flash 8 is not installed. Get flash'. But i think I can manage with that although sometimes I  need a one-on-one help. Yet, I know cannot turn the comment area into chat like am wishing now.

Comment: huh, maybe you do nee flash...at least for browsers that don't support HTML 5...can you upgrade your browser or add flash?

Comment: and meta is a bit different, you're here for support and chat isn't working, its ok to extend the discussion a bit.

Comment: @ Wax alright then, forgive me cos am not IT inclined like most guys on this site but I'll try your suggestion and see.  
Thanks so much for your quick responses. You've been helpful. You should be more than a moderator, lol.

Comment: nope, just a mod around here. Also I'd say that's probably as far as I can go to help you out there. If you are still having trouble try sending an email to the SE team. (use the contact us link at the bottom of any page)